# Adding to a session array

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
 session_start();
 include("#nav.php");
 include("dbconnectie.php");
 echo "Plaatsingen: ";
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM shop");
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo "<table>";
            foreach($result as &$data) {
                echo "<tr>";
                $img = $data['img_url'];
                echo "<td>" . $data["brand"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $data["model"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td> Condition: " . $data["cond"] . "/100 </td>";
                echo "<td> Prijs: &dollar; " . number_format($data["price"],2,",",".") . "</td>";
                    echo "<td> <img src='$img' width='400' height='300' ></img> </td>";
                echo "<td> Plaatsing nummer: " . $data['id_img'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<br>";
            }
        echo "</table>";
        if(isset($_POST['atc']))
        {
            if($_SESSION['on']){
                $myarray = array('0');
                $addtoarray = $_GET['id'];
                array_push($myarray, $addtoarray);
                $_SESSION['cart'] = $myarray;
                echo "Toegevoogd aan uw winkelmandje.";
                var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);
            }else 
            {
                echo "Log eerst in!";
            }

        }
?>

<html>
    <title>Just for kicks</title>
    <header>
    </header>
    <body>
        <form method='post' action=''>
            Plaatsing nummer invoeren:
             <input type='number' name ='id' value ='id'><br>
             <button type="submit" class="submit" name="atc" value="atc">Winkelmadje</button><br><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Between line 25 and 31 I'm trying to add numbers to the session array but I'm not sure how, because this is clearly not working. It doesn't add the number you fill in, at the form part. But it appears it doesn't do anything.

Comment: There are a few things wrong here. Your form is `POST` but you're attempting to retrieve using the `GET`. You are setting `value` to `id` in the form. Remove `value ='id'`. `$_SESSION['on']` is never set so it will never go in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I trimmed your code down to just the bare minimum and added some inline comments. I made the assumption that the contents of `$_SESSION['cart']` is an array.

Please notice:

1. POST was used consistently
2. The value of the input was removed (`value ='id'`)
3. The check for `$_SESSION['on']` was removed

Code

```
<?php
// Start your session.
session_start();

// The form was submitted.
if (isset($_POST['atc'])) {

    // Get the cart so we can append to it.
    // Assuming that the cart is an array.
    $cart = (array)$_SESSION['cart'];

    // Append the user's input to the end of the cart.
    $cart[] = $_POST['id'];

    // Store it in the session.
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;

    // Dump out the session.
    var_dump($_SESSION);
}
?>

<html>
<title>Just for kicks</title>
<header>
</header>
<body>
<form method='post'>
    <label> Plaatsing nummer invoeren:
        <input type='number' name='id'/>
    </label><br>

    <button type="submit" class="submit" name="atc" value="atc">Winkelmadje</button>
    <br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```